# Data array from parent class does not reach View

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Views expect certain variables to be defined by the controllers invoking them. As such, I created my own controller to extend from. This controller, in turn, extends `CI_Controller`.

```
class MainController extends CI_Controller{

static protected $data_bundle;

/**
All classes that will extend MainController should have their own constructors
calling the constructor of MainController.
*/
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $data_bundle["title"] = "";
    $data_bundle["content"] = "";
    $data_bundle["stylesheets"] = array();
    $data_bundle["scripts"] = array();
    $data_bundle["echo_content"] = true;
}

}
```

So, for instance, I may define a Controller for a plain page as follows

```
class PlainPage extends MainController{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct()
    }

    public function page(){
        parent::$data_bundle["title"] = "Plain Page"
        parent::$data_bundle["content"] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
        $this->load->view("mainview", parent::$data_bundle);
    }
}
```

Then, in `mainview.php`, I have the following bit of code:

```
<?php
        foreach($stylesheets as $style){
            echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/$style" />"';
        }
    ?>

    <?php
        foreach($scripts as $script){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/$script"></script>"';
        }
    ?>
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Message: Undefined variable: {stylesheets|scripts}
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Isn't it that when `parent::__construct()` gets called, the `$data_bundle` array should've been initialized? Why is CI/PHP complaining that I have variables undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `self` in parent class constructor when initializing the static property.

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    self::$data_bundle["title"] = "";
    self::$data_bundle["content"] = "";
    self::$data_bundle["stylesheets"] = array();
    self::$data_bundle["scripts"] = array();
    self::$data_bundle["echo_content"] = true;
}
```

But You don't need to use static property in this case, controller should have only one instance, so a instance property is enough.

```
class MainController extends CI_Controller{

protected $data_bundle = array();

/**
All classes that will extend MainController should have their own constructors
calling the constructor of MainController.
*/
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data_bundle["title"] = "";
    $this->data_bundle["content"] = "";
    $this->data_bundle["stylesheets"] = array();
    $this->data_bundle["scripts"] = array();
    $this->data_bundle["echo_content"] = true;
}

}

class PlainPage extends MainController{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct()
    }

    public function page(){
        $this->data_bundle["title"] = "Plain Page"
        $this->data_bundle["content"] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
        $this->load->view("mainview", $this->data_bundle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it precisely. (--,)